# Automatically update annotations in mx:ColumnChart

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex, charts

So, I have a chart (simplified):

```
<fx:Declarations>
    <mx:SolidColor id="solidColor" color="0x90ee90"/>
    <mx:SolidColorStroke id="solidColorStroke" color="0x90ee90"/>
</fx:Declarations>

<mx:ColumnChart id="columnChart" width="100%" height="100%">
    <mx:annotationElements>
        <mx:CartesianDataCanvas id="cartesianDataCanvas" includeInRanges="true"/>
    </mx:annotationElements>

    <mx:horizontalAxis>
        <mx:DateTimeAxis id="dateTimeAxis"/>
    </mx:horizontalAxis>

    <mx:horizontalAxisRenderers>
        <mx:AxisRenderer axis="{dateTimeAxis}"/>
    </mx:horizontalAxisRenderers>

    <mx:verticalAxis>
        <mx:LinearAxis id="linearAxis" baseAtZero="false"/>
    </mx:verticalAxis>

    <mx:verticalAxisRenderers>
        <mx:AxisRenderer axis="{linearAxis}"/>
    </mx:verticalAxisRenderers>

    <mx:series>
        <mx:ColumnSeries xField="time" yField="value" fill="{solidColor}" stroke="{solidColorStroke}"/>
    </mx:series>
</mx:ColumnChart>
```

From time to time in chart is updated `columnChart.dataProvider`. I need to draw over this chart two horizontal lines (for min and max values) and yet something. I know that all of this can be drawn in `annotationElements` on`cartesianDataCanvas`.

The question is: At what point (or what event) should redraw the annotations so that they always match the actual data?

I tried to do it immediately after updating `columnChart.dataProvider`. But it's too early - in `dateTimeAxis` and`linearAxis` did not have time to calculate the new min and max values. It is foolish to calculate them manually.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can try `change` event on `ColumnChart` as:

```
<mx:ColumnChart id="columnChart" width="100%" height="100%" change="handleChange(event)">
</mx:ColumnChart>
```

Then in the method `handleChange`you can do all the work.

Comment: I can try everything and you can believe what you want, but sometimes you need to read the documentation. http://flex.apache.org/asdoc/mx/charts/chartClasses/ChartBase.html#event:change